# Where i can find a list of all supported markdown features for telegram?

Tags: macos, markdown, telegram

I am discovering markdown support in telegram and currently cant find full info anywhere.

I can see  [here](https://core.telegram.org/type/MessageEntity) that there is a lot of entities that telegram supports, but i can't find any syntax for most of these. Actually, default url markdown syntax does not work, so i assume there must be a different syntax. And there is a lot more, like spoiler or blockquotes, for which i can't find telegram syntax. Where can i find any docs for it?

Comment: You're looking at the wrong docs, you'll need to check [the bot api docs](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#formatting-options)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [API formatting options](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#formatting-options).
There are two modes, **legacy mode**:

````
*bold text*
_italic text_
[inline URL](http://www.example.com/)
[inline mention of a user](tg://user?id=123456789)
`inline fixed-width code`
```
pre-formatted fixed-width code block
```
```python
pre-formatted fixed-width code block written in the Python programming language
```
````

**V2 mode:**

````
*bold \*text*
_italic \*text_
__underline__
~strikethrough~
||spoiler||
*bold _italic bold ~italic bold strikethrough ||italic bold strikethrough spoiler||~ __underline italic bold___ bold*
[inline URL](http://www.example.com/)
[inline mention of a user](tg://user?id=123456789)
`inline fixed-width code`
```
pre-formatted fixed-width code block
```
```python
pre-formatted fixed-width code block written in the Python programming language
```
````

Answer (score 0):

On my client (ios 16.5, current) neither of these describe what works here.

- Italics, two underlines: __
- Spoiler: ||
- Boldface: **

These are all I know, but they don’t match either of the above.

A pointer to the source of truth in this would be helpful.